# how to get first value and last value from dataframe column in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I Have Dataframe,I want get first value and last value from DataFrame column.

```
+----+-----+--------------------+
|test|count|             support|
+----+-----+--------------------+
|   A|    5| 0.23809523809523808|
|   B|    5| 0.23809523809523808|
|   C|    4| 0.19047619047619047|
|   G|    2| 0.09523809523809523|
|   K|    2| 0.09523809523809523|
|   D|    1|0.047619047619047616|
+----+-----+--------------------+
```

expecting output is from support column first,last value i.e `x=[0.23809523809523808,0.047619047619047616.]`

Comment: when you say you want first and last value, how you are sorting the data, is it sorted on "count" column?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `collect` but the performance is going to be terrible since the driver will collect all the data, just to keep the first and last items. Worse than that, it will most likely cause an OOM error and thus not work at all if you have a big dataframe.

Another idea would be to use `agg` with the `first` and `last` aggregation function. This does not work! (because the reducers do not necessarily get the records in the order of the dataframe)

Spark offers a `head` function, which makes getting the first element very easy. However, spark does not offer any `last` function. A straightforward approach would be to sort the dataframe backward and use the `head` function again.

```py
first=df.head().support
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
last=df.orderBy(F.monotonically_increasing_id().desc()).head().support
```

Finally, since it is a shame to sort a dataframe simply to get its first and last elements, we can use the RDD API and `zipWithIndex` to index the dataframe and only keep the first and the last elements.

```py
size = df.count()
df.rdd.zipWithIndex()\
  .filter(lambda x : x[1] == 0 or x[1] == size-1)\
  .map(lambda x : x[0].support)\
  .collect()
```

Comment: @oil thanks.can you please suggest outoff above answer which is performance wise best.

Comment: In general, I would avoid sorting. It's expensive. Filtering should be much faster. However, if the dataset is **already** sorted by some column (sorted by spark I mean), you might be able to do better. Let me know if that's the case.

Comment: My dataset is sorted by support column.

Comment: In that case, doing `df.head` and `df.orderBy('support desc).head` could be interesting but I'm not entirely sure about the optimization spark is able to do in that case.

Comment: can u please assist when data is to be grouped before capturing the first and last - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64004622/pyspark-need-help-in-capturing-first-and-last-date-on-dataset-grouped-by-mul

Answer (score 2):

You can try indexing the data frame see below example:

```
df = <your dataframe>
first_record = df.collect()[0]
last_record = df.collect()[-1]
```

**EDIT:**
You have to pass the column name as well.

```
df = <your dataframe>
first_record = df.collect()[0]['column_name']
last_record = df.collect()[-1]['column_name']
```

Comment: `df.collect()[-1]` outputs `Row(column_name=value)` while `df.collect()[-1]['column_name']`extracts just the last *value* of interested column_name, which is what I look for!

Comment: That's a really bad solution as the collect will move first all the data in your driver and then take the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.0.0, spark also have DataFrame function called
[.tail()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.tail.html) to get the last value.

This will return List of `Row` objects:

```
last=df.tail(1)[0].support
```